# Install on R on EC2 Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: r, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My goal is to install R on a EC2 Amazon Linux AMI cluster that I have built.

I have logged into the master and:

When in the home directory:

```
$ sudo yum -y install make libX11-devel.* libICE-devel.* libSM-devel.* libdmx-devel.* libx* xorg-x11* libFS* libX*  readline-devel gcc-gfortran gcc-c++ texinfo tetex

wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.2.2.tar.gz

tar zxf R-3.2.2.tar.gz && cd R-3.2.2

./configure

make

make install
```

I start to see somethings that look like errors after I run the ./configure. Then make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

[

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-243 R-3.2.2]$ ./configure
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
loading site script './config.site'
loading build-specific script './config.site'
checking for pwd... /bin/pwd
checking whether builddir is srcdir... yes
checking for working aclocal... found
checking for working autoconf... found
checking for working automake... found
checking for working autoheader... found
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for bison... no
checking for byacc... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for sed... /bin/sed
checking for which... /usr/bin/which
checking for less... /usr/bin/less
checking for gtar... /bin/gtar
checking for tex... no
checking for pdftex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of the R manuals
checking for pdflatex... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build PDF versions of vignettes and help pages
checking for makeindex... no
checking for texi2any... no
configure: WARNING: you cannot build info or HTML versions of the R manuals
checking for texi2dvi... no
checking for kpsewhich... no
checking for latex inconsolata package... checking for unzip... /usr/bin/unzip
checking for zip... /usr/bin/zip
checking for gzip... /bin/gzip
checking for bzip2... /usr/bin/bzip2
checking for firefox... no
checking for mozilla... no
checking for galeon... no
checking for opera... no
checking for xdg-open... no
checking for kfmclient... no
checking for gnome-moz-remote... no
checking for open... /usr/bin/open
using default browser ... /usr/bin/open
checking for acroread... no
checking for acroread4... no
checking for xdg-open... no
checking for evince... no
checking for xpdf... no
checking for gv... no
checking for gnome-gv... no
checking for ggv... no
checking for okular... no
checking for kpdf... no
checking for open... /usr/bin/open
checking for notangle... false
checking for realpath... /usr/bin/realpath
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking whether gcc needs -traditional... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for gfortran... no
checking for f95... no
checking for fort... no
checking for xlf95... no
checking for ifort... no
checking for ifc... no
checking for efc... no
checking for pgf95... no
checking for lf95... no
checking for gfortran... no
checking for ftn... no
checking for g95... no
checking for f90... no
checking for xlf90... no
checking for pgf90... no
checking for pghpf... no
checking for epcf90... no
checking for g77... no
checking for f77... no
checking for xlf... no
checking for frt... no
checking for pgf77... no
checking for cf77... no
checking for fort77... no
checking for fl32... no
checking for af77... no
checking for fc... no
configure: error: No F77 compiler found
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-31-243 R-3.2.2]$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: You need a Fortran compiler, as clearly said: `error: No F77 compiler found`

Comment: How would I add that? Is that something I add to the first line? Do you by chance have a sudo yum install suggestion?

Comment: `yum search gfortran`

Comment: ok- problem 2: after the fortran complier is added- I get to the ./configure and get this error: checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/home/ec2-user/R-3.2.2':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

Comment: http://superuser.com/